# Firebase, download multiple photos at once to a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have this function inside my react component

```
  pullImages = () => {
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    storageRef.child('images/trump.jpg').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      this.setState({image: url})
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

This is working when I have one image. However, I now have 2 images under my `images` folder in firebase storage. I would like to pull both these images down and set them in state (im guessing in an array) and then I want to be able to loop through these on the page.

I get how to pull one down, not sure how to pull multiple

Answer (score 0):

There's no single API that lets you work with multiple images in one call.  You'll have to make multiple calls, one for each file you'd like to work with.